# Adding values in multi-array but it goes out of bounds

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array, count

I need to count for each position in array how many 1-values is around it. I tried to add another layer of 0 around that and it would work if `r=1` but cant figure it out when e.g `r = 3`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
const int n=10;

int T[n][n]= {
    {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},
    {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},
    {0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1},
    {0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0},
    {1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},
    {1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},
};

int TD[14][14]= {0};

for(int i=2; i<12; i++) 
    for(int j=2; j<12; j++)
        TD[i][j]=T[i-2][j-2];

for(int i=0; i<14; i++) 
{
    for(int j=0; j<14; j++)
        cout<<TD[i][j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        cout<<T[i][j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;

int G[14][14]= {0};

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        cout<<G[i][j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;

int r=1;

for(int i=2; i<13; i++)
    for(int j=2; j<13; j++) 
    {
        for(int ii=i-r; ii<=i+r; ii++)
            for(int jj=j-r; jj<=j+r; jj++)
                G[i][j]=G[i][j]+TD[ii][jj];
    }

for(int i=2; i<12; i++) 
{
    for(int j=2; j<12; j++)
        cout<<G[i][j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

I tried increasing layers of `0s` with increase of array but that just wouldn't work.

So my question is: If that approach is good one if not what kind of solution can you guys suggest ?

Comment: Why declare so many arrays. If you really want to just calculate the 1s for each index you only need a second array of the same dimensions.

Comment: What exactly is the problem (or your question?). I just copy-paste your code into IDE and it ran with no errors...

Comment: Try switching r variable for more than 1 it will go full b-to wallz.
T- array is where 1 and 0 are. TD array is the one with extended bounds (another layer of 0's) and i just smacked the T-array in it. The last one is for counting 1's. Question was simple from begging : "if r=1 but cant figure it out when e.g r=3?" as in the head of question

Comment: Just modify your code so it doesn't access the array out of bounds. And don't use magic numbers such as 12, 13 but use constants.

Answer (score 0):

When approaching any problem where you are counting within a fixed 2D mapping of cells, to determine the number of "neighbors" requires identifying and "boundary" cells and the "interior" cells and then writing an algorithm that works around each boundaries, as well as iterating over each interior cell.

The following example reads the top-row boundary first, then down the left boundary, through the interior, then the right boundary, and finally the bottom row. The code does not consider the value of the cell itself (meaning `cell[i][j]` counts from the possible 8-cells that surround it, but doesn't include its own value in determining the neighbor count if it happened to be a `1`. (you can easily adapt this as desired by activating the commented cell in each section of the neighbor count.

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#define n 10

int main (void) {

    int T[][n]= {
        {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},
        {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},
        {0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1},
        {0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0},
        {1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},
        {1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},
    },
    nrow = sizeof T / sizeof *T,
    ncol = n,
    neighbors = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {    /* loop over rows */
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {   /* loop over cols */
            if (!i) {       /* index of first row */
                if (!j) {       /* top-left corner */
                    neighbors = /*T[i][j]*/   T[ i ][j+1] + 
                                T[i+1][ j ] + T[i+1][j+1];
                }
                else if (j < ncol - 1) {    /* top-inside row */
                    neighbors = T[ i ][j-1] + /*T[i][j]*/ + T[ i ][j+1] +
                                T[i+1][j-1] + T[i+1][ j ] + T[i+1][j+1];
                }
                else if (j == ncol - 1) {   /* top-right corner */
                    neighbors = T[ i ][j-1] + /*T[i][j]*/ 
                                T[i+1][j-1] + T[i+1][ j ];
                }
            }
            else if (i < nrow - 1) {    /* interior cells */
                if (!j) {       /* left-side vertical */
                    neighbors = T[i-1][ j ] + T[i-1][j+1] +
                                /*T[i][j]*/ + T[ i ][j+1] +
                                T[i+1][ j ] + T[i+1][j+1];
                }
                else if (j < ncol - 1) {    /* inner cells */
                    neighbors = T[i-1][j-1] + T[i][j-1] + T[i+1][j-1] +
                                T[i-1][ j ] + /*T[i][j]*/ T[i+1][ j ] +
                                T[i-1][j+1] + T[i][j+1] + T[i+1][j+1];
                }
                else if (j == ncol - 1) {   /* right-side vertical */
                    neighbors = T[i-1][j-1] + T[i-1][ j ] +
                                T[ i ][j-1] + /*T[i][j]*/
                                T[i+1][j-1] + T[i+1][ j ];
                }
            }
            else if (i == nrow - 1) {   /* last row */
                if (!j) {       /* bottom-left corner */
                    neighbors = T[i-1][ j ] + T[i-1][j+1] +
                                /*T[i][j]*/ + T[ i ][j+1];
                }
                else if (j < ncol - 1) {    /* bottom-inside row */
                    neighbors = T[i-1][j-1] + T[i-1][ j ] + T[i-1][j+1] +
                                T[ i ][j-1] + /*T[i][j]*/ + T[ i ][j+1];
                }
                else if (j == ncol - 1) {   /* bottom-right corner */
                    neighbors = T[i-1][j-1] + T[i-1][ j ] +
                                T[ i ][j-1]   /*T[i][j]*/;
                }
            }
            std::cout << "T[" << i << "][" << j << "]: " << neighbors << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/neighbors
T[0][0]: 2
T[0][1]: 3
T[0][2]: 1
T[0][3]: 2
T[0][4]: 1
T[0][5]: 4
T[0][6]: 2
T[0][7]: 4
T[0][8]: 3
T[0][9]: 1
T[1][0]: 3
T[1][1]: 3
T[1][2]: 2
T[1][3]: 3
T[1][4]: 2
T[1][5]: 6
T[1][6]: 3
T[1][7]: 4
T[1][8]: 3
T[1][9]: 3
...
T[8][0]: 5
T[8][1]: 5
T[8][2]: 5
T[8][3]: 5
T[8][4]: 3
T[8][5]: 5
T[8][6]: 3
T[8][7]: 4
T[8][8]: 4
T[8][9]: 1
T[9][0]: 2
T[9][1]: 2
T[9][2]: 2
T[9][3]: 2
T[9][4]: 1
T[9][5]: 3
T[9][6]: 2
T[9][7]: 1
T[9][8]: 3
T[9][9]: 1
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.